# Relational Database in C with simple queries

Tags: c, relational-database

I am trying to implement a relational database in C. The program is supplied with a config_file.txt that contains the number of relations in the database followed by the names of the relations on subsequent lines. Then I am supplied with a InsertRelationNameHere.sch file for each relation which contains the structure of the tuples( number of attributes on first line, followed by attributes and the format of the data they contain). Additionally, I am supplied with a InsertRelationNameHere.dat file which is a binary file with the actual information stored in each relation.

I have three queries so far:

nattr *InsertRelationNameHere* -(which prints out the # of attributes in'InsertRelationNameHere')

tuplen *InsertRelationNameHere* -(prints the number of bytes that each tuple takes up in the .dat file, length of tuple)

count *InsertRelationNameHere* -(prints the number of tuples that are in each relation)

The problem that I am having is in the count query:

When I use this query I am getting a segfault and I am not sure why.

Here is my func.c that contains the code for all of the queries:

```
#include "globals.h"

FILE* check;

void nattr(char * str){
    char* token;
    const char s[2] = ".";
    strcpy(tempstr2, str);
    strncat(tempstr2,".sch", 4); // appends '.sch' extension to the file name
    if((check =(FILE*)fopen(tempstr2, "r")) == NULL){  // opens "InsertFileNameHere.sch"
        printf("", token);
        strcpy(token, strtok(tempstr2, s));
        fprintf(stdout,"Error: Invalid relation -- %s\n", token);
    }else{
        fscanf(check, "%d", &numattr);
        fprintf(stdout, "%d\n",numattr);
    }

    fclose(check);
}

void tuplen(char * str){

    char* token;
    const char s[2] = ".";
    strcpy(tempstr2, str);
    strncat(tempstr2,".sch", 4); // appends '.sch' extension to the file name
    if((check =(FILE*)fopen(tempstr2, "r")) == NULL){  // opens "InsertFileNameHere.sch"

        printf("", token);
        strcpy(token, strtok(tempstr2, s));
        fprintf(stdout,"Error: Invalid relation -- %s\n", token);
    }else{
        sumattr = 0;
        dummy = 0;
        fscanf(check, "%d", &numattr); // reads first line, gets number of lines to read
        for(i = 0; i < numattr; i++){
            fscanf(check, "%s", tempstr3); // reads first string on line, does nothing with it
            fscanf(check, "%s", tempstr3); // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            fscanf(check, "%d", &dummy); // reads the int in third position on line, this is the number of bytes of the attribute
            fgetc(check);   // moves past the '\n'
            sumattr += dummy; // adds the amount of bytes for each attribute to the total
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", sumattr);
    }

    fclose(check);
}

void count(char * str){
    char* token;
    const char s[2] = ".";
    strcpy(tempstr2, str);
    nattr(tempstr2);// sets numattr to the number of attributes in file: tempstr2
    tuplen(tempstr2);
    puts("here");
    printf("%s %s", numattr, sumattr);
    strncat(tempstr2,".dat", 4); // appends '.sch' extension to the file name
    if((check =(FILE*)fopen(tempstr2, "rb")) == NULL){  // opens "InsertFileNameHere.sch"
        printf("", token);
        strcpy(token, strtok(tempstr2, s));
        fprintf(stdout,"Error: Invalid relation -- %s\n", token);
    }else{

        for(i = 0; i< numattr; i++){    // these fscanf functions are only called to move through
            fread(tempstr3, 1, sumattr, check);
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", i);
            if(feof(check)){
                break;
            }
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", i);
    }
    fclose(check);
}
```

Here is my globals.h header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 15
#define MAX_REL 10

FILE* files[MAX_REL*2];  // Array of FILES that are the '.sch' and '.dat' files for relations
char tempstr1[MAX_LEN+1], tempstr2[MAX_LEN+1], tempstr3[MAX_LEN], tempstr4[MAX_LEN], tempstr5[MAX_LEN], temp;
int num_rel, i, numattr, sumattr, dummy;
FILE* conf; // configure file
```

Also here is my Prog.c file where my main method is:

```
#include "globals.h"

int nattr(char * str);
//void fileOpener(FILE * conf);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // Error checks for correct arguments
    if( argc != 4){
        fprintf(stdout, "Check usage");exit(1);
    }
    if((conf = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stdout, "could not open file %s\n", argv[1]);exit(1);
    }
    if((quef = fopen(argv[3], "r")) == NULL){
            fprintf(stdout, "could not open file %s\n", argv[2]);exit(1);
    }
    //fileOpener(conf);
    scanf("%s", tempstr1);                  // maybe you could try a switch here, getting some funky input characteristics
    while(strcmp(tempstr1, "exit") != 0){
        if(strcmp(tempstr1, "exit") == 0){
            strcpy(tempstr2, tempstr1);
            strcpy(tempstr3, tempstr1);
            strcpy(tempstr4, tempstr1);
            strcpy(tempstr5, tempstr1);
            exit(1);
        }

            while(strcmp(tempstr1, "nattr") == 0){
                scanf("%s", tempstr2);
                strcpy(tempstr3, tempstr1);
                strcpy(tempstr4, tempstr1);
                strcpy(tempstr5, tempstr1);
                nattr(tempstr2);
                scanf("%s", tempstr1);
                if(strcmp(tempstr1, "exit") == 0){
                    exit(1);
                }if(strcmp(tempstr1, "tuplen") != 0){
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(strcmp(tempstr1, "tuplen") == 0){
                scanf("%s", tempstr2);
                strcpy(tempstr3, tempstr1);
                strcpy(tempstr4, tempstr1);
                strcpy(tempstr5, tempstr1);
                tuplen(tempstr2);
                scanf("%s", tempstr1);
                if(strcmp(tempstr1, "exit") == 0){
                    exit(1);
                }if(strcmp(tempstr1, "tuplen") != 0){
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(strcmp(tempstr1, "count") == 0){
                scanf("%s", tempstr2);
                strcpy(tempstr3, tempstr1);
                strcpy(tempstr4, tempstr1);
                strcpy(tempstr5, tempstr1);
                count(tempstr2);
                scanf("%s", tempstr1);
                if(strcmp(tempstr1, "exit") == 0){
                    exit(1);
                }if(strcmp(tempstr1, "tuplen") != 0){
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the files ive been using to test these functions
Student.sch:

```
5
Name   S  25
Major  S  4
Minor  S  4
Totcr  I  4
Majcr  I  4
```

Student.dat:

```
536d 6974 682c 526f 6265 7274 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0050 5359 0043 5349
0000 0000 3900 0000 2757 6f6f 6473 2c4a
616e 6500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 4353 4900 4255 5300 0000 0061 0000
0044 5261 6d73 6579 2c45 6c61 696e 6500
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0042 5553 0050
5359 0000 0000 6b00 0000 5857 6861 7274
6f6e 2c54 6f6d 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 4255 5300 5053 5900 0000 0075
0000 0062 4261 6b65 722c 4e6f 726d 6100
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0042 494f
0043 5349 0000 0000 2700 0000 19
```

config_file.txt:

```
2
Students
Courses
```

query_file.txt: (This file is not used yet but is required for the code to run properly)

```
nattr     Students
nattr     Norelation
tuplen    Badrelation
tuplen    Students  
infattr   Students  Minor
infattr   Students  Majorcr
infattr   Students  Totcr
infattr   Courses   Badattr
infattr   Courses   CName
infattr   Courses   Credits
count     Students
count     Student
count     Corses
count     Courses
project   Students     Name
project   courses      Credits
project   Students     Minor
project   Students     Majcredit
project   Courses      Credits
project   Courses      Instr
select    Students     Major !=  "BUS"
select    Students     Totcr   <   39
select    Courses      Credits  ==  3
select    Courses      Instr  ==  "KELLER"
select    Students     Name  >  40
select    Courses      Instr  ==  "Keller"
select    Courses      Credits  ==  "Keller"
select    Courses      Instructor  ==  "Keller"
quit
```

The expected outputs for the first two queries should look like this:

```
gcc Prog3.c func.c globals.h   
./a.out Prog3.c config_file.txt query_file.txt
nattr Students
5
nattr Norelation
Error: Invalid relation -- Norelation
tuplen Students
41
tuplen Norelation
Error: Invalid relation -- Norelation
```

Then when use "count Students" I get a segfault.

If it is any help, my program segfaults at the line in the tuplen function `strcpy(token, strtok(tempstr2, s));` only when "tuplen()" is called through the count function, but not when I use the tuplen query on its own.

I know this is a long question, I am sorry! But I tried to keep it as short as possible while still explaining myself. If anything is unclear please let me know and I can elaborate. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I will not read the whole question, you need to pick a concrete problem and explain it breifly, that's a lot of stuff.

Comment: If the output is wrong, there is something wrong with your logic. If you get a segfault somewhere in your program, you could retrieve where that comes from and post another question about why there is a segfault at that specific piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of these lines in `count`.

```
nattr(tempstr2);// sets numattr to the number of attributes in file: tempstr2
tuplen(tempstr2);
```

You should replace this with

```
nattr(str);// sets numattr to the number of attributes in file: tempstr2
tuplen(str);
```

After the call of `nattr`, the buffer `tempstr2` contains "Student.sch". When you call `tuplen` with this string, it appends .sch which yields "Student.sch.sch". Opening this file fails because it doesn't exist. 
The code executed in such case is

```
printf("", token);
strcpy(token, strtok(tempstr2, s));
...
```

The first line does nothing. Since `token` is not initialized and contains some random value, `strcpy` tries to copy the output of `strtok` into this random location. And this causes the segmentation fault.

You could have avoided this segmentation fault by passing `str` to `nattr` and `tuplen`. But the code executed in case the `fopen` fails is bad and needs to be changed. The use of global variables is also bad.

---

Get rid of your global variables. This is bad programming and error prone. 
Use a struct and you pass around a pointer to it. Make it clear what function initializes the struct and that no other function overwrites its fields by mistake.

Here is an example how you should write nattr().

```
// returns the nattr value of the given table or -1 if failed getting the value 
int nattr(char * str){
    char tmpstr[MAX_LEN+1+4];
    FILE * f;
    int numattr = -1;

    strcpy(tmpstr, str);
    strncat(tmpstr,".sch", 4); // appends '.sch' extension to the file name
    f = fopen(tmpstr, "r");  // opens "InsertFileNameHere.sch"
    if (f == NULL){ 
        printf("Error: Invalid relation -- %s\n", str);
        return -1;
    }

    // Try read numattr, leave it unchanged if fails. numattr is then -1
    if (fscanf(f, "%d", &numattr) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("%d\n", numattr);
    fclose(f);
    return numattr;
}
```

Since I have some more time, here is tuplen

```
// Return the byte size of a tuple or -1 if failed 
int tuplen(char * str){
    char tmpstr[MAX_LEN+1+4];
    char attrName[MAX_LEN+1];
    char attrType[2];
    int numattr = -1, sumattr = 0, attrSize;
    FILE * f;

    strcpy(tmpstr, str);
    strncat(tmpstr,".sch", 4); // appends '.sch' extension to the file name
    f = fopen(tmpstr, "r");
    if (f == NULL){ 
        printf("Error: Invalid relation -- %s\n", str);
        return -1;
    }

    if (fscanf(f, "%d", &numattr) != 1)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0; i < numattr; i++){
        if (fscanf(f, " %s %1s %d", attrName, attrType, &attrSize) != 3)
            return -1; // try reading the three fields of one line
        sumattr += attrSize; // adds the amount of bytes for each attribute to the total
    }
    printf("%d\n", sumattr);
    fclose(f);
    return sumattr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help, You gave me what i needed to get my program all cleaned up and working! I appreciate it!